# Lack of Implicit Conversions for Strings and STL Containers

Tags: c++, stl, containers, implicit-conversion, stdstring

Why doesn't C++ have implicit conversion to `bool` defined for `std::string` and STL containers when writing code like

```
if (!x.empty()) { ... }
```

instead of more shorter

```
if (x) { ... }
```

when `x` is of type `std::string` or for example `std::vector`?

I'm also puzzled by the fact that `std::string` (in C++03) doesn't implicit convert to `const char*` in  STL examples like

```
std::string s("filename");
std::ofstream(s.c_str();
```

Comment: If you think this hurts the usability of C++, stay away from my code.

Comment: Could you please give me some motives?

Comment: That seems more like a rant than a question. (Also, I heavily disagree with your assumption that those implicit conversions would make coding easier/better.)

Comment: Feel free to add them. Moreover, use `x.empty()` instead of `x.size()`, `empty()` is always constant-time whereas `size()` is linear in some containers.

Comment: @FredericS: Thanks for the tip about `empty()`. But adding these requires me to inherit std::string into a new class right, as these conversions must be added as member functions?

Comment: In C++11, you can pass `std::string` directly as the filename for file streams. No need for a conversion there.

Comment: Why does this question have so many downvotes?  It better not be because people disagree that these conversions should exist.  That's certainly not a valid reason to downvote.

Comment: @Nordlöw By the way, I actually agree with you about the `ofstream` thing being nasty, but that's the fault of C++03's `fstream`, not the fault of a lacking implicit conversion. Luckily, the C++11 version fixes this by having a constructor that *does* take a `string` directly: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Languages such Python and even D allow these conversions. I believe the question is motived. Or is it because of my rant-like formulation. If so I can rephrase my question.

Comment: @Nordlöw indeed conversion operators cannot be global, they must be added as member functions, my bad. In this case adding them is problematic (inheriting from std::string works but is not clean)

Comment: Unexpected implicit conversions is a big, _big_, BIG problem!

Comment: @Nordlöw: I *suspect* the downvotes have more to do with the way the question is phrased, rather than the question itself.

Comment: @FredericS: What do you mean by inheriting from `std::string` no being clean?

Comment: Ok, I rephrased the question to not being a rant. Excuse me.

Comment: @Nordlöw maybe "clean" is not the best word. I want to say that it won't work with existing code using `std::string`, you'll have to use your new type to have this behavior.

Comment: @Nordlöw Yeah, that's better - changed my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @Nordlöw, `std::string` has no virtual destructor, so you better have a very clear and good reason to inherit from it. If you distribute this in a library with clear instructions not to use it polymorphically, you know you'll get 50 emails in a week from people complaining about how it doesn't work after using it polymorphically.

Answer (score 5):

One reason to not do this in C++ is that conversions of that sort have a tendency to lead to [subtle bugs](http://tempastic.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/perils-of-implicit-conversions-in-c.html).

Stroustrup specifically addresses your question about `c_str()` in The C++ Programming Language [3rd ed.]:

> Conversion to a C-style string could have been provided by an `operator const char*()` rather than `c_str()`. This would have been provided the convenience of an implicit conversion at the cost of surprises in cases in which such a conversion was unexpected.